# r/sparkline/win&loss/chnage bar colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, sparklines

Working on a win/loss sparkline in R. Data coded 1 for win and -1 for loss.  Can get basic structure with ggplot and following code:

```
puck <- data.frame(game=c("g1", "g2", "g3", "g4"),
                 wnls=c(-1, 1, -1, 1))
head (puck)
library(ggplot2)
# sparkline via barplot, v1
plot1<-ggplot(data=puck, aes(x=game, y=wnls)) +
     geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.5)
plot1
```

Understand how to change all bars to one color.  However, want to code the wins blue and losses red.  Suggestions on how to do this?
Thanks, RB

Comment: `ggplot(data=puck, aes(x=game, y=wnls, fill=factor(wnls))) + geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.5) + scale_fill_manual(values=c("-1"="red", "1"="blue"))`

Comment: The use of `aes`thetics such as `fill=` and `color=` on levels or values within the data is fairly fundamental to `ggplot2`. I suggest you go through the *Articles* (except perhaps the Developer articles) at https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to define a new column with wins and losses and then map `fill` to aesthetics:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# sparkline via barplot, v1
plot1<-ggplot(data=puck %>% 
                mutate(win_loss = ifelse(wnls < 0, "loss", "win")), 
              aes(x=game, y=wnls, fill = win_loss)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.5)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green"))
plot1
```

[image]

Comment: I recommend the use of named vector for `values=`.

Comment: @r2evans This is a very good approach!!! I didn't think of that.

Comment: I've found so many "silent bugs" when not using named manual-values that I am hair-triggered to always name it. I say "silent" because nothing is wrong to `ggplot2` so long as the length of vectors is about what it expects regardless of the order of distinct values.

Comment: Thank you all. Looks like several alternatives.  This should do it.